# a sufficient way to show logs in a graphical interface using whiptail in bash

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to represent log files via the whiptail's infobox. The only setback is that I don't want to scroll down through hundreds of log lines. Is there a way to make the scroll bar go to the end of the box automatically?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

there seems no option for whiptail to do that. Im happy to know as well if someone can make it.
However, maybe you want to try

```
vim -M + <filename>
```

- not possible to make change in the file
- start at the end of the file
- get benefit from VIM nice features. e.g. searching, navigation ...

Comment: well i found a way around it instead of scrolling up  i just reversed the reading from the file using `tac`

Answer (score 0):

If you use dialog instead of whiptail, you can use `--tailbox` or `--tailboxbg`. They work like `tail -f`. You can't scroll up and down, but neither does whiptail's infobox.